# ionic 3- couldn't find module path

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-view

[image: **Could find module 'path in ionic' **]

I was install plugin of signaturePad from npm ! Somehow I came up with this error! What does it mean basically?! What do I need to do to solve this! Anyone please help me out! I am giving my app.module.ts file here !

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';


import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import {TabsPage} from "../pages/tabs/tabs";


import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import {ContactPage} from "../pages/contact/contact";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      MyApp,
      HomePage,
      ListPage,
      TabsPage,
      ContactPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
      MyApp,
      HomePage,
      ListPage,
      TabsPage,
      ContactPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
      BarcodeScanner,
      Camera
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: can you please put your `app.module.ts`

Comment: Given now ! please help me out ! :)